# Why doesn't Mathematica solve this non linear (fractional) ODE?

Tags: syntax, nonlinear

```
a1 =  NDSolve[{y1''[x] - 0.1 y1[x]^0.25 == 0, y1'[0] == 0, y1[1] == 1},
```

I get the following errors - 
Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0.^0.75 encountered

Infinity::indet: "Indeterminate expression 0.

ComplexInfinity encounteredNDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0

Answer (score 4):

```
a1 = 
  NDSolve[{y1''[x] - 0.1 y1[x]^0.25 == 0, y1'[0] == 0, y1[1] == 1}, y1, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[y1[x] /. a1, {x, 0, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Mathematica 10.4.1 on Windows 10 (64 bit)

Comment: This doesnt work in Mathematica 9.0.1.0?

Comment: @Prasad You should update?